# jQuery datepicker popup twice

Tags: jquery, jsf, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using IE7 (have to), Java Server Faces 1.2, latest version of jQuery datepicker for dynamically generated data rows situtation. Also need support user manully enter dates. Datepicker works fine if not manully enter dates. The strange behave is when user type dates manully, then you move mouse to any part of the window, click, the orignal calendar closes (good), but then it pops out again (bad). Seems the focus() thing play some kind role for this, since if I write a simple datepicker without the last focuse, things are fine, but in order for handle dynamically AJAX generated rows, I have to using that focus().

If I manully type dates, then push Enter key, things are fine. Also, Firefox works fine but we required to support IE7.

The code as below (you can ignore backbean related stuff). Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq("[id$=fmv]").live('click', function() {
        jq(this).datepicker( {
            showOn : 'focus',
            duration : 10,
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy',
            yearRange : '-1:+1',
            showButtonPanel : true,
            closeText : 'Close',
            showWeek : true,
        }).focus();
    });
});
</script>
```

Input:

```
    <h:inputText id="fmv"
                     size="10"
                     maxlength="10"
                     style="background-image:url      ('../../../jquery/images/calendar1.png');
                       background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right;"
                       title="#{msgs['choose.date.lbl']}"
                       value="#{pItem.dateOfStudy}"
                       validator="#{pItem.validate}"
                       onkeyup="submit();"
                       onchange="submit();"
                       name="fmv"         
                       valueChangeListener="#{pItem.dateChangeListener}"> 
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" timeZone="America/New_York" dateStyle="short" type="date"/>
            </ice:inputText>
```

I tried to make a very simple xhtml see blow. The generated html file is big due to our project includes. Then I just cut the jquery script and inputtext html part and put it into a html file, the problem can not be recreated. Odd. 
xhtml file:

```
     <ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq("[id$=fmv]").live('click', function() {
        jq(this).datepicker( {
            showOn : 'focus',
            duration : 10,
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy',
            yearRange : '-1:+1',
            showButtonPanel : true,
            closeText : 'Close',
            showWeek : true
        }).focus();
    });
});
</script>



<h:inputText id="fmv" size="10" maxlength="10"
    style="background-image:url('../../../jquery/images/calendar1.png');
                       background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right;"
    title="#{msgs['choose.date.lbl']}" value="#{pItem.dateOfStudy}"
    validator="#{pItem.validate}" partialSubmit="true" onkeyup="submit();"
    onchange="submit();" name="fmv"
    valueChangeListener="#{pItem.dateChangeListener}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" timeZone="America/New_York"
        dateStyle="short" type="date" />
</h:inputText>

     </ui:composition>
```

Comment: can you post the markup that this xml creates?

Comment: From generated source code (IE view source), due to we using Facelet includes, and data rows is in the table, I can't see much. Let me see if I can recreate problem in a small xhtml file.

Comment: I made a very simple xhtml, here is markup:  <script     type="text/javascript"> var jq = jQuery.noConflict(); jq(document).ready(function() { jq("[id$=fmv]").live('click', function() { jq(this).datepicker( { showOn : 'focus', duration : 10, changeMonth : true, changeYear : true, dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy', yearRange : '-1:+1', showButtonPanel : true, closeText : 'Close', showWeek : true }).focus(); }); }); </script> <div class="selTbl"> <input id="frmFP:fmv" maxlength="10" name="frmFP:fmv" onchange="submit();" onkeyup="submit();" size="10" style="background-image:url(&#39;../../../jquery/images/

Comment: Can you post it as an edit to your question please

Comment: Yes, I added xhtml file part.

Comment: hmmm - As you say it's hard to see the problem if we can't recreate it. I'm not sure that the markup you have posted is valid and that's always the first place I'd start when trying to debug this. My advice would be to split out your markup, presentation and behaviour more rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the on click just leave it on focus. This means when the input is focused.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready(function() {
        jq("[id$=fmv]").datepicker({
            showOn : 'focus',
            duration : 10,
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy',
            yearRange : '-1:+1',
            showButtonPanel : true,
            closeText : 'Close',
            showWeek : true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Example with separate function:

```
function addCalendar(obj)
{
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready(function() {
        jq(obj).datepicker({
            showOn : 'focus',
            duration : 10,
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy',
            yearRange : '-1:+1',
            showButtonPanel : true,
            closeText : 'Close',
            showWeek : true
        });
    });
}
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But to handle dynamically genearted rows (each rows has a calendar after user performed search), I have to use 'live', so I have to use some event in live(event, function).

Comment: Try then jq("input.someClass").datepicker(...);
You can have only one input with given ID, by the valid HTML definition, which make sense. So add to these inputs `class="someClass"`, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Rolice, I did before using css class, but it can not solve AJAX updates situation, only by using live(), then dynamically generated components can show datepicker properly. But some how I hit this show twice problem on IE7. My code is based on the post http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-ajax-and-livequery/#comments.

Comment: OK, then separate in a function like: `function addCalendar(obj)` and instead of jq("input.someClass") you may call it like this:
jq(obj).datepicker(..) where obj is the input object. Tell me if it helps. :)

Comment: Use different ids for different controls. Document ready is executed when the page is loaded, not when the AJAX is completed. This should be done by you in the AJAX handler, where you could skip livequery, I think. How do you execute AJAX requests?

Comment: Thanks Rolice, but the input objects are dynamically generated, some times 2 rows, sometimes 300 rows, depends on the search results, thus live() has to be used in order to attach the datepicker handler to those rows that has 'fmv' as the id or has some class (as you suggested). Without using live, that I tried before, no calendar will be showing.

Comment: I got it fixed finally. We actually using icefaces 1.2. When I put partialSubmit="true" in ice:inputText field, the calendar no longer pop up twice after user manually enter date. But select a date in calendar will not tigger date submit to the backbean, unless 2nd row of calender date got selected. That's why I added onchange="submit();" in my first post. Now I added "onSelect: function() {jq(this).submit();}," in jquery datepicker, removed onchange="submit();" from ice:inputText (which causes calendar pop up again), all things working as expected under IE7.

Comment: `$("input.test").each(function(index) {
    $(this).datepicker({
        ...
        ...
    });
});`

Try this after loading is complete and tell me the result. :)